# CMake: set folders for build products

Tags: windows, cmake, intel

Using CMake 2.8 on Windows 10, Intel compiler.

I'm building all 4 combinations of `{debug, release}`, `{32bit, 64bit}`, and want all build intermediates (e.g. obj) to be placed in 4 separate folders accordingly, relative to the project folder.

Tried setting:

```
CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR
PROJECT_BINARY_DIR
CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR
CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
```

To no avail, and all the products end up in the project folder (where the `CMakeLists.txt` resides).

Comment: `all the products end up in the project folder (where the CMakeLists.txt resides).` - Do not run `cmake` from source directory. Create separate build directories for every 4 combinations, and run `cmake` from there. This is known as *out-of-source builds*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All build artifacts are placed in the directory cmake was run from (NOT necessarily where CMakeLists.txt resides).

So, for each configuration simply CD into the desired output directory and run cmake from there.